# JSP request.getParameter error

Tags: jsp

I have a hidden parameter in a jsp page using struts.

```
    <html:hidden property="currentDescription"></html:hidden>
```

It is grabbing the correct values from a properties file and being rendered in the html.

I want to display a line of code based on this being populated, but it's not working.

```
    <% if(request.getParameter("currentDescription") != "") { %>
```

I've tried the `.equals` as well and that throws an exception.

Comment: What exception did it throw?

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is no property value. So it returns `null` and you may be getting `NullPointerException` after using `equals()` as parameter value is `null`

Comment: That is the exception I am getting when using equals()

Comment: that clearly means you do not have any value for the parameter.

Comment: So if I set the value to  value="<%=currentDescription%>", this would resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't set a `value` for the property:

```
<html:hidden property="currentDescription" value="blahblah"/>
```

Second, it is better when to do it like that

```
<% if("".equals(request.getParameter("currentDescription"))) { %>
```

More better to use [`JSTL`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)

```
<c:if test="${not empty currentDescription}>
// do something
</c:if>
```

Comment: So how can I set the value? I tried value=<%currentDescription%> but that threw an error.

Comment: You set the value as in the answer
`<html:hidden property="currentDescription" value="blahblah"/>`

Comment: And if `currentDescription` **value** was sent by the server in any scope, you could simply read it using the `el` operator `$`

Comment: So it would be like this `<html:hidden property="currentDescription" value= "${currentDescription}"/>`

Comment: Setting the value="${currentDescription}" this didn't get the value of the currentDescription. The html rendered is <input type="hidden" name="currentDescription" value="">, without setting the value the html rendered as 
<input type="hidden" name="currentDescription" value="Here was the description from the properties file">.

Comment: Where do you store `currentDescription` value?

Comment: <fhms:CurrentDescriptionTag />

Comment: What is `fhms` thing?

Comment: From a .tld file                                                                    <tag>
    <name>CurrentReportDescriptionTag</name>
    <tag-class>com.fhms.rptweb.tags.CurrentReportDescriptionTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
  </tag>